# Undefined variable: branch. Codeigniter 3 form_dropdown()

Tags: codeigniter

I want to populate a list of names in a dropdown list using form_dropdown(...) and fetch the matching name accordingly.

Both my model and controller classes seem to be working fine, but I am unable to pass in the second argument to the form_dropdown() function in my view. I get the error "Undefined variable: branch",  I tried dumping the values returned by getBranch() and it works.
I have 3 different PHP scripts for the views: 'index' (showing the data in form tables etc), 'form'(where I fill in the details for a new student) and 'index-datatable' (Jquery script for the datatable). Please note, all the views are in one directory/folder 'students' as seen in the controller's index function.
I am new to Codeigniter 3.

**Controller Class**

```
public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        is_login();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('menu_model', 'menu');
        $this->load->model('my_model', 'my');
        $this->load->model('students_model', 'students');
    
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['branch'] = $this->students->getBranch(); //Get the names of branches. 

        $data['title'] = 'Student List Home';

        $data['page'] = 'students/index';
      
        $data['datatable'] = 'students/index-datatable';

        $this->load->view('back/layouts/main', $data);
  
    }
```

**Model Class**

```
    function getBranch() {
        $this->db->select('id');
        $this->db->select('name');
        $this->db->from('branch');        
        
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();

        $branch_id = array('-CHOOSE-');
        $branch_name = array('-CHOOSE-');

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
            array_push($branch_id, $result[$i]->id);
            array_push($branch_name, $result[$i]->name);
        }
        return $branch_result = array_combine($branch_id, $branch_name);
        
    }
```

**View (Form, not index)**

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="branch">Branch</label>
                    <?php
                    $attributes = 'class = "form-control" id = "branch"';
                    echo form_dropdown('branch', $branch, set_value('branch'), $attributes);
                    
                    ?>
                </div>
```

***Add method***

```
public function add() {
        if (!$_POST) {
            $input = (object) $this->students->getDefaultValues();
        } else {
            $input = (object) $this->input->post(null, true);
        }

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('package_name', 'Title', 'required', [
            'required' => 'Text can not be empty'
                ]
        );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('package_fee', 'Text', 'required', [
            'required' => 'Text can not be empty'
                ]
        );

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('duration', 'Text', 'required', [
            'required' => 'Text can not be empty'
                ]
        );

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('category_id', 'Text', 'required', [
            'required' => 'Text can not be empty'
                ]
        );

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $data['title'] = 'Register a new Student';
            $data['page'] = 'students/form';
            $data['form_action'] = base_url("students/add");
            $data['input'] = $input;
            $this->load->view('back/layouts/main', $data);
        } else {

            $data = [
                'title' => $this->input->post('title', true),
                'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname', true),
                'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname', true),
                'othername' => $this->input->post('othername', true),
                'gender' => $this->input->post('gender', true),
                'dob' => $this->input->post('dob', true),
                'nationality' => $this->input->post('nationality', true),
                'address' => $this->input->post('address', true),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email', true),
                'phone_number' => $this->input->post('phone_number', true),
                'education' => $this->input->post('education', true),
                'occupation' => $this->input->post('occupation', true),
                'nationalidtype' => $this->input->post('nationalidtype', true),
                'id_number' => $this->input->post('id_number', true),
                'prev_driving_exp' => $this->input->post('prev_driving_exp', true),
                'photo' => $this->input->post('photo', true),
                'license_type_id' => $this->input->post('license_type_id', true),
                'branch_id' => $this->input->post('branch_id', true),
                'group_id' => $this->input->post('group_id', true)
            ];


            if (!empty($_FILES['photo']['name'])) {
                $upload = $this->students->uploadImage();
                $data['photo'] = $upload;
            }

            $this->students->insert($data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Student Data added successfully');

            redirect(base_url('students'));
        }
    }
```

***Main View*** only showing where the other pages is loaded. some scripts taken off, that is the header and footer scripts.

```
<div id="wrapper">


            <?php $this->load->view('back/layouts/_sidebar') ?>



            <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">


                <div id="content">


                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-white topbar mb-4 static-top shadow">


                        <button id="sidebarToggleTop" class="btn btn-link d-md-none rounded-circle mr-3">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </button>


                        <?php $this->load->view('back/layouts/_topbar') ?>
                    </nav>

                    <?php $this->load->view('back/pages/' . $page) ?>

                </div>

                <?php $this->load->view('back/layouts/_footer') ?>


            </div>


        </div>
```

Comment: Is the `index` function in your controller rendering the form that you posted?
If not, could you show the controller method that is rendering the form?

Comment: The controller has a method `add` that calls the form. But not called in the index. If I tried to call the form in the index I get an error.   Maybe you could show me how that can be done. Thanks.

Comment: I can't help without seeing the code. You could try changing this line in the `index` function `$this->load->view('back/layouts/main', $data);` to `$this->load->view('students/form', $data);` to include the form directly and see if that removes the undefined variable error. If that does work, you're probably doing something in the `back/layouts/main` template file that causes the variables to be lost. If you need more help, please edit your post and add the code for the `add` function from the controller and for the `back/layouts/main` template file.

Comment: Okay, I shall try the above in a bit. but what code would you like to see please?

Comment: The code for the `add` function in the controller and the code for the `back/layouts/main` template file, please.

Comment: I am trying to edit the original question in order to add the requested, getting formatting error so unable to update after editing. Will get that up soonest. Thanks

Comment: I have added the `add` and `main` view codes as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing a `branch` variable to the form template in the `add` function.

Add the `branch` in the `if`, like this:

```
public function add() {

    // ...

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        $data['branch'] = $this->students->getBranch(); //Get the names of branches. 
        $data['title'] = 'Register a new Student';
        $data['page'] = 'students/form';
        $data['form_action'] = base_url("students/add");
        $data['input'] = $input;
        $this->load->view('back/layouts/main', $data);
    } else {

        // ...

   }

}
```

Comment: Many thanks Marleen. You have been helpful!

Comment: Not sure, I am able to see the exact branch_id in the form data payload but the `insert` isn't working. I tried using actual id from input form (not from form_dropdown()) and the insert works. Not sure, please is there something I am missing? Been on this for hours now. :(

Comment: The name of the `branch` selectbox is `branch`, not `branch_id`, so you probably need to change this line `'branch_id' => $this->input->post('branch_id', true),` to `'branch_id' => $this->input->post('branch', true),` in the `add` function.
If that does not work, please post the exact database error you're getting.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. Aside your correction, in the view, the first argument was branch instead of branch_id. Working fine now. Thanks.